# unpivot issue with multiple like columns

Tags: sql-server, unpivot

I have a CSV import file that I have no control over concerning the column names or format. The headers consist of `id,[temperature range 1],[temperature range 2],[temperature range 3],[temperature range],[temperature range 5],[temperature range 6],[temperature range 7],[temperature range 8], [temperature range 9],[temperature range 10],[temperature range 11],[temperature range 12], [Pressure Range 1],[Pressure Range 2],[Pressure Range 3],[Pressure Range 4],[Pressure Range 5], [Pressure Range 6],[Pressure Range 7],[Pressure Range 8],[Pressure Range 9], [Pressure Range 10],[Pressure Range 11],[Pressure Range 12],[Calcite Saturation 1],[Calcite Saturation 2],[Calcite Saturation 3],[Calcite Saturation 4],[Calcite Saturation 5],[Calcite Saturation 6],[Calcite Saturation 7],[Calcite Saturation 8],[Calcite Saturation 9],[Calcite Saturation 10],[Calcite Saturation 11],[Calcite Saturation 12]`.

I have been able to unpivot the table using this code:

```
Select id,Temp,Psia,CalciteX
from (
    Select id,[temperature range 1],[temperature range 2],[temperature range 3],[temperature range 4],[temperature range 5],[temperature range 6],[temperature range 7],[temperature range 8], [temperature range 9],[temperature range 10],[temperature range 11],[temperature range 12],[Pressure Range 1],[Pressure Range 2],[Pressure Range 3],[Pressure Range 4],[Pressure Range 5], [Pressure Range 6],[Pressure Range 7],[Pressure Range 8],[Pressure Range 9],[Pressure Range 10],[Pressure Range 11],[Pressure Range 12],[Calcite Saturation 1],[Calcite Saturation 2], [Calcite Saturation 3],[Calcite Saturation 4],[Calcite Saturation 5],[Calcite Saturation 6],[Calcite Saturation 7],[Calcite Saturation 8],[Calcite Saturation 9],[Calcite Saturation 10], [Calcite Saturation 11],[Calcite Saturation 12]
    from frenchcreekscale where id ='10009-2019111114.1/P' ) as src

UNPivot ( Temp for Temps in([temperature range 1],[temperature range 2],[temperature range 3],[temperature range 4],[temperature range 5],[temperature range 6],[temperature range 7],[temperature range 8], [temperature range 9],[temperature range 10],[temperature range 11],[temperature range 12]) ) AS Temps
 
UNPivot ( Psia for Pressures in([Pressure Range 1],[Pressure Range 2],[Pressure Range 3],[Pressure Range 4],[Pressure Range 5],[Pressure Range 6],[Pressure Range 7],[Pressure Range 8],[Pressure Range 9], [Pressure Range 10],[Pressure Range 11],[Pressure Range 12]) ) AS Pressures

UNPivot ( CalciteX for CalciteXs in([Calcite Saturation 1],[Calcite Saturation 2], [Calcite Saturation 3],[Calcite Saturation 4],[Calcite Saturation 5],[Calcite Saturation 6],[Calcite Saturation 7],[Calcite Saturation 8],[Calcite Saturation 9],[Calcite Saturation 10], [Calcite Saturation 11],[Calcite Saturation 12]) ) AS CalX
```

This is the partial output I am getting:

```
id                   Temp Psia CalciteX
-------------------- ---- ---- --------
10009-2019111114.1/P 70   0    0.165885
10009-2019111114.1/P 70   0    0.180097
10009-2019111114.1/P 70   0    0.195601
10009-2019111114.1/P 70   0    0.211319
10009-2019111114.1/P 70   0    0.226902
10009-2019111114.1/P 70   0    0.241826
10009-2019111114.1/P 70   0    0.25538
10009-2019111114.1/P 70   0    0.267159
10009-2019111114.1/P 70   0    0.276571
10009-2019111114.1/P 70   0    0.283237
10009-2019111114.1/P 70   0    0.286532
10009-2019111114.1/P 70   0    0.286462
10009-2019111114.1/P 70   147  0.165885
10009-2019111114.1/P 70   147  0.180097
10009-2019111114.1/P 70   147  0.195601
10009-2019111114.1/P 70   147  0.211319
10009-2019111114.1/P 70   147  0.226902
10009-2019111114.1/P 70   147  0.241826
10009-2019111114.1/P 70   147  0.25538
10009-2019111114.1/P 70   147  0.267159
10009-2019111114.1/P 70   147  0.276571
10009-2019111114.1/P 70   147  0.283237
10009-2019111114.1/P 70   147  0.286532
10009-2019111114.1/P 70   147  0.286462
10009-2019111114.1/P 70   278  0.165885
10009-2019111114.1/P 70   278  0.180097
etc
```

It should only be 12 records:

```
id                   Temp 
-------------------- ----
10009-2019111114.1/P 70
10009-2019111114.1/P 80
10009-2019111114.1/P 90
10009-2019111114.1/P 100
10009-2019111114.1/P 110
10009-2019111114.1/P 120
10009-2019111114.1/P 130
10009-2019111114.1/P 140
10009-2019111114.1/P 150
10009-2019111114.1/P 160
10009-2019111114.1/P 170
10009-2019111114.1/P 180
```

With the other fields tied to the id.

I am not understanding how to unpivot the next column with out generating the multiple records.

Answer (score 0):

`pivot` and `unpivot` work best when you only provide them the columns needed for the pivot. Your `src` subset contains columns for 3 `unpivot`'s. If you split those up in separate common table expressions (CTE's), you can then join them back on the `id` column.

Please note that joining on `id` alone will not be enough. This will still give you the multiple rows. You want the value for `[temperature range 1]` on the same line as `[Pressure Range 1]` and `[Pressure Range 1]`. So you must add that to your join criteria.

In my simplified example I used the single rightmost charater from the column name to construct this extra join criterium (giving me `1` and `2`). Your full solution should the last two numbers from the column names (giving you  `1` to `12`).

**Simplified sample data**

```
create table MyTable
(
  id int,
  A1 nvarchar(4),
  A2 nvarchar(4),
  B1 nvarchar(4),
  B2 nvarchar(4)
);

insert into MyTable (id, A1, A2, B1, B2) values
(1, '1A11', '1A21', '1B11', '1B21'),
(2, '2A11', '2A21', '2B11', '2B12');
```

**Simplified solution**

```
with cte_A as
(
  select upA.id, upA.AValue, upA.AType
  from (select id, A1, A2 from MyTable) a
  unpivot (AValue for AType in ([A1], [A2])) upA
),
cte_B as
(
  select upB.id, upB.BValue, upB.BType
  from (select id, B1, B2 from MyTable) b
  unpivot (BValue for BType in ([B1], [B2])) upB
)
select ca.id, right(ca.AType, 1) as Num, ca.AValue, ca.AType, cb.BValue, cb.BType
from cte_A ca
join cte_B cb
  on  cb.id = ca.id                            -- match on id
  and right(cb.BType, 1) = right(ca.AType, 1); -- match on type (bring A1 and B1 to same line)
```

**Sample output**

```
id Num AValue AType BValue BType
-- --- ------ ----- ------ -----
1  1   1A11   A1    1B11   B1
1  2   1A21   A2    1B21   B2
2  1   2A11   A1    2B11   B1
2  2   2A21   A2    2B12   B2
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=35ccd3a4e1ed32f1198beee7f0af68ad)

---

**Existing query**

Looking back on my solution: you can also apply the "extra join criterium" to your existing query. Add something like the following:

```
... 
where right(CalX.Temps, 2) = right(CalX.Pressures, 2)
  and right(CalX.Temps, 2) = right(CalX.CalciteXs, 2);
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=91eeb4b00d0af6d279babbf7ec6361bf) that applies this solution to a simplified version of your query.